# Symfony constraint-mapping do not see env variables

Tags: symfony, environment-variables, symfony6, symfony-config-component

I have following `.env` file:

```
VAR=8888
```

I want to use this variable from `.env` file in the constraint config file. So I do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<constraint-mapping xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping/constraint-mapping-1.0.xsd">
    <class name="App\Entity">
        <property name="page">
            <constraint name="EqualTo">
                <option name="value">%env(string:VAR)%</option>
            </constraint>
        </property>
    </class>
</constraint-mapping>
```

But the env value is not interpreted. It just prints sth like this: `\"%env(string:VAR)%\"`

Also I have tried first to set parameter in `config.yaml`, like this:

```
parameters:
    var: '%env(resolve:VAR)%'
```

And then try to use like this:

```
...
<constraint name="EqualTo">
    <option name="value">%var%</option>
</constraint>
...
```

But it also does not work.

I am using php v. 8.1 with symfony v. 6.1
I have tried to remove cache and restart docker containers but it didn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution from [this](https://www.facebook.com/pawel.malisak) user is to create a custom validator, similar to this:

```
class CustomConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private string $var

    public function __construct(string $var
    {
        $this->var = $var
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint): void
    {
        if ($value === $this->var) {
            return;
        }
        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)->addViolation();
    }
}
```

Then create a custom constraint:

```php
class CustomConstraint extends Constraint
{
    public string $message = 'Invalid VAR';
}
```

Then set up parameter in `services.yaml`:

```
...
services:
    CustomConstraintValidator:
        arguments:
            $var: '%env(resolve:VAR)%'
```

And then use it in XML file like this:

```xml
...
<property name="page">
     <constraint name="CustomConstraint" />
</property>
```